# Find value in adjacent cell in excel

Tags: excel

This is sort of what Im working with:

```
Col A     Col B     Col C
X         100       10
X         200       15
X         300       20
Y         100       12
Y         200       18
Y         300       24
```

What I want to do is to find the value in Col C where Col A is Y and Col B is 200. I used VLOOKUP to find the value in Col C where Col B is a certain value, but since I have multiple cells in Col B with the same values I need to specify which one of them I need to match with the value in Col C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a formula like:

```
=INDEX(C1:C6, SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6="Y")*(B1:B6=200)*ROW(C1:C6)), 0)
```

Note, however, that this will only work if the combination of values in column A and B are unique.

Comment: Can you explain how this formula works? what does the C9 and C10 have to do with anything?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I had used those cells as input to test the formula. I have updated the formula to directly state `Y` and `200` as the combination to lookup.

Comment: ah, yes! Although, I didnt have to use INDEX. I just used =SUMPRODUCT((A:A=B24)*(C:C=G33)*(D:D)) and it works! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. Be aware that the formula you are using now will only work with numeric values, and if you were to have non-unique combinations of the values in column A and B then you would get a sum returned instead.